# WM_NCCALCSIZE, custom client area, and scroll bars

Tags: winapi, mfc, scintilla

I have an MFC app that embeds a Scintilla text edit control. I want to customize the Scintilla control to display some custom controls next to the vertical scrollbar. Essentially, I want to  render some controls in the orange area below, where the green area represent the scroll bars:

[image: Desired client area]

I tried overriding the WM_NCCALCSIZE message of the Scintilla window and subtracting an offset from the right side of the client rectangle. Here is the code:

```
void CScintillaCtrl::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* lpncsp)
{
    CWnd::OnNcCalcSize(bCalcValidRects, lpncsp);
    lpncsp->rgrc[0].right -= 100;
}
```

However, this causes the vertical and horizontal scroll bars to reposition themselves to account for the smaller client width, as shown below:

[image: Scrollbar offset from client offset]

I'm not sure if this behavior is caused by Scintilla or Windows. Is there a way I can adjust the client area and preserve the positions of the scroll bars?

Comment: "I'm not sure if this behavior is caused by Scintilla or Windows" - Windows: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/nccalcsize.png

Comment: You could add your custom controls on the left side and save you a lot of trouble ;-).

Comment: Haha, I wish it were that easy ;)

Comment: The bahaviour of WM_NCCALSIZE is correct. As itis the intention of the message it will add a border AROUND your control not inside of it!

Answer (score 0):

I found a Scintilla specific solution. I can use the `SCI_SETMARGINRIGHT` command to add a margin to the right side of the client area, and then render my controls inside that.